# Is there a statistical test to compare two heatmaps/response surfaces or two curves?

Tags: functional-data-analysis, heatmap

I am conducting a series of experiments in which I analyse the effect of the order of treatment of bacterial cells with different concentrations of two compounds (Drug 1 and Drug 2). The values in the cells are % reduction of bacterial biomass compared to control (Drug 1 = 0 and Drug 2 = 0) based on the average of three replicates.

[image: heatmaps]

As you can see, the heatmaps appear to be different and there are other reasons to believe that the order of treatment has a significant effect. Is there any reasonable way to compare these heatmaps?

If this is impossible, I would be happy to compare two curves of biomass reduction formed by fixing the concentration of one of the drugs and comparing orders of treatment. For example, if we fix Drug 2 concentration at 10^6 pg/mL, then we can see that the order of treatment Drug 1 first, then Drug 2 (D1->D2) seems to kill bacteria more efficiently than the reverse order (D2->D1). I was thinking of using ANCOVA (https://www.biostathandbook.com/ancova.html) to compare two curves, but I am not sure that this approach is valid here.

Apologies if my explanation sounds confusing, I am out of my depth here. Any suggestions as to how formalise the comparisons would be greatly appreciated.

[image: curves]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! [tag:functional-data-analysis] might be worth learning about.

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I have considered several options to analyse my data.
1. Non-linear ANCOVA - may not be appropriate if curves represent qualitatively different models.
2. Two-way ANOVA (variable 1 = order of treatment, variable 2 = drug concentration) with multiple comparisons correction. Potentially extendable to three-way ANOVA to include second drug (variable 1 = order, variable 2 = drug 1 concentration, variable 3 = drug 2 concentration)?
3. Functional ANOVA (FANOVA; https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2003.10.021) to compare curves.
What do you think would be the most appropriate approach?

Comment: I encourage you to read a bit about [tag:functional-data-analysis].